# Jitsi Meet in CefSharp

Tags: cefsharp

I am trying to create a VB.NET Windows Forms application with Video Conferencing in a Web Browser. I am now trying "Jitsi Meet" because I could not get "Google Meet" to work at all. I have Jitsi Meet working to the point where I can create and or log into a meeting with another PC and I can see myself in on each PC, but cannot see any video or audio from the other PC. I can see a "Fellow Jitster" window, but it says "Participant has stopped Camera" and "Participant is muted" on both PC's. I can create a working meeting between these 2 PCs using Google Chrome but I need this to function in my application using a CefSharp Browser. I have found these command line settings on line and the "enable-media-stream" command line argument helped me get to where I can see myself on the origin PC, but I still cannot see the feed from the "Fellow Jitster".

```
    settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream", "1")
    settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("use-fake-ui-for-media-stream", "1")
    settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-speech-input", "1")
    settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-usermedia-screen-capture", "1")
    settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Remove("mute-audio")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer...I apparently had an old "User Agent" string. This is the one that works...

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.141 Safari/537.36

Comment: Are you able to do Screen sharing like how the options are available on a regular browser ? I am facing an issue that I can connect to the conference with audio and camera but the Screen Share option does not pop up, like how it does when a regular Chrome or Firefox browser is used.

Comment: I do still have this issue...The Jitsi web site does not display properly on my Microsoft Surface Pro. There is a big black area to the left of the blue background of the Jitsi site and the page has no functionality. I am thinking this may be a limitation of that small capacity of the Surface?

Comment: I found something else that works better but run into a deployment glitch. If it works, I will post the details here.

Comment: Try this WebView2 control created by Michael Russin. Works very well. There is a browser control as well if you want to use it. Look for "MtrDev.WebView2.WinForms". Some issues to watch out for - ping me and will be glad to guide you.